# Count number of attributes with a certain value

Tags: xpath-2.0

I have a survey, the result of which has the following format

```
<xml><z:row ID="1" ows_Q1="Yes" ows_Q2="No"
                   ows_Q3="Yes" ows_Q4="Yes" ows_Q5="No" />
</xml>
```

The attribute names `ows_Q1`, `ows_Q2` etc. are the actual questions, and hence these are dynamic. And there can be any number of such attributes based on the number of questions in the survey. I need to count the results based on the yes/no answer provided the user and show a summary of user's response. For e.g. for the above survey result summary will be:

- Yes: 3
- No: 2

Is there a way to count the number of attributes based on the attribute value? I tried the below xpath syntax to count number of Yes responses, but it returns the count as 1. This is returning the count of nodes but not attributes:

```
count(//row[@*="Yes"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution

```
count(//row/@*[.="Yes"])
```

This returns the number of attributes for a given value.